# How to trace or catch all errors in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I have a NodeJS server and sometimes I get errors that I cannot trace. I installed `express-async-errors` to prevent such errors from stopping the server, but sometimes an error goes through, for example this one:

```
[2023-12-19T16:45:33.726Z] SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (~/server/node_modules/node-ipinfo/dist/src/ipinfoWrapper.js:93:43)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:138:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

The only place in my code where I use IP-info is wrapped in try-catch:

```
// Top of file has this:
// const IPinfo = require('node-ipinfo');

// Several routes use this code:
let ipinfo = new IPinfo(config.ipinfo);
try {
  let info = await ipinfo.lookupIp(ip);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("IP Info error for ip address: " + ip + " (" + req.ip + ")")
}
```

An error like this causes the server to stop; I restart it thanks to pm2.

How can I trace and debug this error?